# variable was wrong in debug mode using .netframework 3.5

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a problem with some code when step debug (vs2017 .net framework 3.5 ,debug mode)
here is code

```
  class Program {

      static void Main(string[] args) {
        DataParameter para = new DataParameter("12");
      }
    }
    enum TestEnum {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
    class DataParameter {
        private bool c33;
        public DataParameter(string name) {
            TestEnum ta = TestEnum.A;
            c33 = ta == TestEnum.A || ta == TestEnum.B;//after execute :c33 = false
            Name = name;//after execute :c33 = true
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUFJF.png)
[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjd6h.png)

Comment: `c33` is `true` on both of your screenshots, as expected. So what is the problem?

Comment: This looks like it's working as expected

Comment: Your screenshots are equal.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a breakpoint it stops before executing the code. So when it stops on line 24, the assignment to c33 has not been done and c33 has the default value of a bool member, which is false. After executing line 24 it is set to true as expected.